# I wanted to map my class to database using Object Relational Mapping

Tags: python, oop, sqlalchemy

I have been working on these task since yesterday, i have three files one is the testing file, the second one is sql code is in that one while the third one contains my class.

6-model_class.py contains the testing file

```
#!/usr/bin/python3                                                                                                                                           

"""                                                                                                                                                              Start link class to table in database                                                                                                                    """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
import sys                                                                                                                                                   
from model_state import Base, State                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
from sqlalchemy import (create_engine)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                                                       
   engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://{}:{}@localhost/{}'.format(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], 
   sys.argv[3]), pool_pre_ping=True)
   
   Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

model_state.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3                                                                                                                                           
"""                                                                                                                                                              The file contain the class                                                                                                                               """                                                                                                                                                          
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine                                                                                                
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Base = declarative_base()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

class State(Base):                                                                                                                                               
  """                                                                                                                                                              
     This class will contain class attribute                                                                                                                  
  """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  __tablename__ = "states"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,                                                                                                                                   
  autoincrement=True, nullable=False)                                                                                                              
  
  name = Column(String(128), nullable=False)
```

The third one contains my sql file and it contains the name of my database

```
-- Create database hbtn_0e_6_usa                                                                                                                             
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS hbtn_0e_6_usa;                                                                                                                 
USE hbtn_0e_6_usa;                                                                                                                                           
SHOW CREATE TABLE states;
```

i converted the main file to executable file, if i run it
./6-model_class.py root mypassword name_of_database
it will print out a very long error which i capture the last part of the error
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'nOk0rie_22@localhost' (-2)") (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)